# Track and trace geolocation & temperature with blockchains

Tags: geolocation, blockchain, iot, ethereum

For my internship, I need to implement a blockchain based solution to manage a drug supply chain. The management of this supply chain implies to track-and-trace (geolocate) a drug on the chain, but also to monitor the storage temperature to see if the cold chain is respected. For that I also intend to use IOT, where a device will feed information on the blockchain solution. However, I have a few questions that I can't find easier.

The first one is that I don't know if I should use ethereum or not, since each time that a new block is added (the block representing the update on the information about the product on "real-time") I will to use money. Is there any solution for that? Or do I need to create a blockchain with javascript?

The second question is that I absolutely don't know from where to begin in order to implement IOT on the block chain. I searched on research site, but they only talk about it, without presenting any example...

The third one is more a confirmation than a question since I want to know if my idea to use an IOT to track and manage products on a supply chain can be done on a wide scale, since the bigger a blockchain the slower is the time to add a block because of the consensus mechanism. So it means that my "real time" tracking on truly be "on time" since there would be a waiting time before the block is added to the blockchain. If the time is just a few seconds to minutes, then there is no problem, but because the number of block will rapidly increase because of the real time tracking (1 block each minute for each storage or transport vehicles I was planning for) that this problem of scalability makes it impractible.

I'm thanking anybody in advance who will help me solve these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1) Whether you use Ethereum or another blockchain that may be better suited for this purpose is completely up to you. I expect you will get a lot of opinionated answers on this. Ethereum is certainly the most popular blockchain for a use like this, but that does not mean it is the best for your app. Over the last several years we have seen many new blockchains with lower/no fees, faster block times, and increased scalability. I would suggest doing some research into various "Supply Chain", "Enterprise", and "Business" blockchains, as these are likely the type you are looking for and will cost very little in blockchain fees due to them not being as widely used as Ethereum is.

#2) You will have to settle on a blockchain before you can start prototyping or looking for examples, as each one will be different. For storing "log" data for your application there are generally 2 options: Storing data in a smart contract on Ethereum (or an Ethereum-like blockchain), or storing data in the OP_RETURN field of a transaction on Bitcoin or a bitcoin-based blockchain. The latter is likely easier to get started with and is simpler to understand, you just put the data in a transaction and send it (to yourself, even).

#3) Yes, there a special purpose blockchains created exactly for this purpose that are meant to ingest large amounts of data and that can scale to meet the needs of an application like you describe. Some blockchains have block times of 1 minute or less meaning that on average, you could update the data every minute if you were willing and able to pay the blockchain fee to include the data in each new block (personally I would suggest a longer interval, such as every 5-10 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Emercoin NVS](https://emercoin.com/en/documentation/blockchain-services/emernvs) technology and Emercoin ([testnet](https://medium.com/@emer.tech/emer-testnet-why-and-how-8e37bea2e5ea)) blockchain to upload you data into it. By creating some "name label" with `name_new` command, you can thereafter upload chain of modifications for values of your name. Blockchain has command `name_show` (shows recent uploaded value) and `name_history` (shows all chain of uploaded values). You can view/debug your uploaded values within [Emercoin Testnet Explorer](http://testnet.emercoin.com/), tab `NVS`.

Regarding "use money".
I can give you (or anyone else) 100 test EMCs, for free. Just write your tEMC address in comments here. 100tEMCs will be enough for ~100,000 records within Testnet. Thus, I think, it is more than enough for your test tasks.

If you need to use your service for production, you need to use the "real blockchain" (with high trust), no testnet. Anyway, EMCs are very cheap right now, and you can buy 100EMSs for ~$5 only. I think, this is not big deal for your organization.

Ask more questions, and I will be happy to assist you here with this technology.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a permissioned / private environment that does not transfer value or store value, a blockchain specialised in value transfer, like Ethereum, is not a good choice.

Choosing a blockchain that is specialised in untrusted value writes simplies creating your product a lot. Some good choices include:

- [BigchainDB](https://www.bigchaindb.com/)
- [HyperLedger SawTooth - comes with a stock supply chain example](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/0-8/examples/supplychain/overview.html)